# Transferring an ifstream into an unordered map of a string and vector of strings

Tags: c++, stdvector, ifstream, unordered-map

```
int main() {
  std::unordered_map<std::string, vector<std::string>> pronunciation_dict;
  std::vector<std::string> phonomes;
  std::string pronun;
  {
    std::ifstream pronun_file("/srv/datasets/cmudict-0.7b-words ");
    for (std::string words; pronun_file >> words >> pronun;) {
    phonomes.push_back(pronun);
    pronunciation_dict[words] = phonomes;
  }
  while (std::cin >> words)
  std::cout << pronunciation_dict[words] << '\\n';
}
```

example of some of the dataset:

```
ABBS  AE1 B Z
ABBY  AE1 B IY0
ABC  EY1 B IY2 S IY2
ABCO  AE1 B K OW0
ABCOTEK  AE1 B K OW0 T EH2 K
ABCS  EY1 B IY2 S IY2 Z
ABDALLA  AE2 B D AE1 L AH0
ABDALLAH  AE2 B D AE1 L AH0
ABDEL  AE1 B D EH2 L
ABDELLA  AE2 B D EH1 L AH0
ABDICATE  AE1 B D AH0 K EY2 T
ABDICATED  AE1 B D AH0 K EY2 T AH0 D
ABDICATES  AE1 B D AH0 K EY2 T S
ABDICATING  AE1 B D IH0 K EY2 T IH0 NG
ABDICATION  AE2 B D IH0 K EY1 SH AH0 N
ABDNOR  AE1 B D N ER0
ABDO  AE1 B D OW0
ABDOLLAH  AE2 B D AA1 L AH0
ABDOMEN  AE0 B D OW1 M AH0 N
ABDOMEN(1)  AE1 B D AH0 M AH0 N
ABDOMINAL  AE0 B D AA1 M AH0 N AH0 L
```

My problem is trying to implement the broken-up strings from the dataset into my unordered map. I don't know how I should attempt to put the first string into my key then the rest into the result.

Comment: use `https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline` to read lines

Comment: Note that `std::cout << pronunciation_dict[words]` will not work, unless you overload `operator<<` yourself.  There is no standard `operator<<` to print a `vector`.

Comment: Small question: Your dataset keys are sorted (the first word in each line)...why are you using an `unordered_map` to store them instead of a sorted `map`?

Answer (score 3):

Typically you'd read in an entire line with `std::getline`, then use an `std::istringstream` to parse that into individual pieces, something along this general line:

```cpp
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> entries;

std::string buffer;
while (std::getline(infile, buffer)) {
    std::istringstream parser(buffer);

    std::string word;

    parser >> word;
    std::vector<std::string> phonomes{std::istream_iterator<std::string>(parser), {}};

    entries[word] = phonomes;
}
```

If you care a lot about speed, it may be faster to parse out the pieces of the line using `std::string::find_first_of` and `find_first_not_of`, but it's more difficult, and since this is combined with file I/O, it probably won't make a huge difference in any case.

Comment: Great example and use of `std::istream_iterator`, Had to turn it into a [Full Example](https://godbolt.org/z/rj83Mqn36) to check. There is a lot to be said for the niceties of C++.